# optimise IN subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization, in-subquery

I have a workers table and an associated workerGeofence table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `workergeofences` (
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `WorkerID` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `GeofenceID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isActive` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=107 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I need to return only workers who have at least one entry in the workerGeofences table with an isActive of 1.

I'm able to get the desired outcome withe following:

```
    SELECT distinct w.ID, Title, FName, SName, Email, Birthday, Address, Phone, description,
 companyID 
FROM Workers w WHERE companyID = ? 
and w.ID IN (SELECT WorkerID FROM WorkerGeofences WHERE isActive <> 0)
    limit ?,10
```

but the in subquery is exhaustive as when I run the explain, I can see it is scanning the entire table. How would I get around this?

Comment: You can't show us only half the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , your join is wrong! you are not comparing any common column on both table, you should add where workerGeofences.workerID = w.id like this:

```
SELECT  w.ID, Title, FName, SName, Email, Birthday, Address, Phone,
        description, companyID
    FROM  Workers w
    join  workerGeofences
    WHERE  workerGeofences.workerID = w.ID companyID = ?
      and  w.ID IN (
        SELECT  WorkerID
            FROM  WorkerGeofences s
            WHERE  isActive <> 0
              and  s.workerID = w.id
                   )
    limit  0,10
```

And second, you are not selecting anything from the second table, so the join is unessesary and in your IN statement, you are not comparing the right ID's so your query should be:

```
SELECT  w.ID, Title, FName, SName, Email, Birthday, Address, Phone,
        description, companyID
    FROM  Workers w
    WHERE  companyID = ?
      and  w.ID IN (
        SELECT  WorkerID
            FROM  WorkerGeofences s
            WHERE  isActive <> 0
              and  s.workerID = w.ID
                   )
    limit  0,10
```

Also, you can use EXISTS() for that.

```
SELECT  w.ID, Title, FName, SName, Email, Birthday, Address, Phone,
        description, companyID
    FROM  Workers w
    WHERE  companyID = ?
      and  exists 
      ( SELECT  1
            FROM  WorkerGeofences s
            WHERE  isActive = 1
              and  s.workerID = w.ID
      )
    limit  0,10
```

Comment: Use EXISTS and drop the DISTINCT.. or use a JOIN.

Comment: I used exists, and I cant drop the distinct since we dont know if there are duplicates in his table @Arth

Comment: Assuming each worker row is unique in workers (fairly safe assumption) you can drop the DISTINCT.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track, but you shouldn't need `select distinct`. This slows down queries, unless you know there are duplicates -- and that is unlikely because you are selecting `WOrkers.Id`.

```
SELECT w.* 
FROM Workers w 
WHERE w.companyID = ? AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM workerGeofences wg
              WHERE w.ID = wg.WorkerID AND wg.isActive <> 0
             )
LIMIT ?, 10;
```

Then, for this query, you want indexes on `Workers(CompanyId, Id)` and  `workerGeofences(WorkerId, isActive)`.

Note:  I just put in `select *` for convenience.  I assume all the columns are coming from the `Workers` table.

Comment: (This is better than the accepted answer because (1) it emphasizes `EXISTS`, not the slow `IN` and (2) it mentions indexes which may help.)

Comment: @RickJames It is, I upvoted it but I had already accepted the other answer before this was posted. I was already using indexes thankfully and went for the exists option in the accepted answer

Comment: @GordonLinoff one question: is there any reason why you checked isActive <> 0 instead of isActive = 1? I thought checking <> is more expensive on the query?

Comment: The Optimizer has no way of knowing how many different values `isActive` can take on.  You started with `<> 0`, Gordon copied you.  However it is potentially inefficient -- it involves two ranges "< 0" and "> 0".  `=1` is more efficient because it is only one range, "= 1".  So Sagi's 3rd example has that improvement.

Comment: Actually, the inequality shouldn't really make a difference.  It is the second key in the index, so an inequality will still use the index (an equality would be slightly better, but that is a micro-optimization).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness using JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT w.ID,
       w.Title, 
       w.FName, 
       w.SName, 
       w.Email, 
       w.Birthday, 
       w.Address, 
       w.Phone, 
       w.description, 
       w.companyID
  FROM Workers w 
  JOIN WorkerGeofences wg
    ON wg.workerID = w.id
   AND wg.isActive = 1
 WHERE w.companyID = ? 
 LIMIT ?,10
```

Comment: If there is more than one `isActive` row for a worker, it will generate duplicate rows.  Then the `DISTINCT` kicks in to remove the dups -- thereby making it less efficient than the `EXISTS` solution.

Comment: @RickJames Yep, you are probably right.. although I think the optimiser may result in the same query. I included it more for completeness, but the comment will be useful to travelling eyes,